# Опять ошибка в правилах Розенталя?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Это тема «Обобщающие слова при однородных членах предложения».

Однородный ряд, обособленный двоеточием и тире,   входит **в осложненное или сложное предложение,** и ставится вопрос о сохранении тире перед запятой. Розенталь  приводит два предложения, в одном из которых **тире сохраняется**, а в другом – **поглощается запятой**. https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103 п.8

***Наряду с** иными стихийными бедствиями, как-то: **пожар, град, начисто выбивающий хлебные поля, ненастье или, наоборот, великая сушь**, — есть в деревне ещё одно бедствие* (Сол.) *Владелец тщательно осведомляется о ценах на разные большие произведения, как-то: **муку, пеньку, мёд и прочее**, но покупает только небольшие безделушки* (Г.)

Всё бы хорошо, но как объяснить **разное решение для сходных вариантов**?  В обоих случаях после однородного ряда стоит запятая. К примеру, в теме «Обособленные приложения» есть такое правило: тире опускается, если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится запятая. https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111 п.10  Похожее правило есть в теме «Прямая речь внутри слов автора».

Так почему же здесь  **не действует единое правило,** по которому тире не должно ставиться в обоих случаях? Ошибка или нет?  Если это неправильное редактирование Розенталя, то какой  пример должен здесь быть, чтобы **запятая не поглотила тире**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**На мой взгляд, примеры у Розенталя верные.** Правда, объяснение некорректное.

Я проштудировал Нацкорпус и обнаружил следующую тенденцию: действительно, **в подавляющем большинстве подобных случаев тире не используется, ставится лишь запятая**, например:

."..Как только надо математически установить количественные соотношения между пространственными образами или между величинами, рассматриваемыми в механике, **как то: силою, массою, скоростью, ускорением и временем, то** все эти величины надо сперва измерить приемами..."

На мой взгляд, именно тут и идет "поглощение тире запятой", про которое говорил Розенталь, так как она находится перед частью составного союза. В этом случае предложение легко читается, это "то" позволяет читателю быстро и четко разграничить ряд однородных членов от последующей части предложения **без использования тире**. Хотя, конечно, никакого поглощения тут нет, просто оно и так легко читается.

Однако в Нацкорпусе я увидел и такое предложение:

"Пособие им можно давать не деньгами, а различными предметами, необходимыми для первоначального обзаведения хозяйством, **как то: скотом, семенами, земледельческими орудиями**, или, наконец, выдавать те же самые деньги..."

Нетрудно заметить, что тире и тут не ставится. Однако здесь оно было бы уместно, без него оно читается значительно сложнее, однородные члены как бы сливаются со следующей за ними частью предложения, присоединяемой разделительным союзом "или".

К тому же не стоит забывать, что тире позволит передать дополнительные оттенки значения или интонационное оформление предложения, которое как раз в примере выше было бы не лишним, без этого  тире предложение разбухает от обилия запятых, тире позволит сосредоточить внимание читателя и указать четкое разделение предложение на части.

**Таким образом**, я считаю, что верной тактикой в таких предложениях с однородными членами  будет по умолчанию ограничиваться запятой, а к тире прибегать лишь при необходимости, исходя из ваших конкретных задач.

Comment: Большое спасибо, Игорь, за ответ, очень приятно ваше внимание к проблемам правописания.  Я отвечу чуть позже – надо обдумать ваш анализ и предложить какое-то свое решение.

Comment: Спасибо вам! Ждём с нетерпением! Ваше влияние на мои знания в области русского языка, да и на меня в целом — нельзя переоценить.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала я приведу отрывок из книги Солоухина «Капля росы»:

*Наряду с иными стихийными бедствиями, **как-то: пожар, град, начисто выбивающий хлебные поля, ненастье или, наоборот, великая сушь**, есть в деревне еще одно бедствие, о котором, может быть, и не знают многие городские люди. Вдруг ударит набат, и, когда все выбегут на улицу смотреть, где горит, бьющий в набат крикнет: «К Самойловскому лесу бегите, коровы объелись!»*

В учебном примере текст сокращен и поставлено тире.

1. Итак, **в  авторском тексте нет тире, ставится только запятая**.

Я полагаю, что  тире   и  не должно ставиться, то есть правильная запись такая:  *Наряду с иными стихийными бедствиями, **как-то: пожар, град, начисто выбивающий хлебные поля, ненастье или, наоборот, великая сушь**, есть в деревне ещё одно бедствие.*

Здесь «старшей конструкцией» является предложение с обособленным оборотом: *Наряду с иными стихИйными бедствиями, есть в деревне ещЁ одно бедствие.*  Это предложение лежит в основе **интонационной схемы**, обозначенной **двумя ударениями.**

Однородный ряд вписывается  в эту схему **в упрощенном виде**: увеличенная пауза на месте двоеточия не делается, а интонация всего предложения похожа на такой вариант *Наряду с иными стихийными бедствиями, **как, например, пожар, град, начисто выбивающий хлебные поля, ненастье или, наоборот, великая сушь**, есть в деревне ещё одно бедствие*.

Соответственно, это **общее правило** для подобных конструкций.

2. Мне представляются возможными еще **такие варианты**:

(1) Наряду с иными стихийными бедствиями – **пожар, град,  ненастье или великая сушь**,  есть в деревне ещё одно бедствие.  Здесь также «поглощение» тире запятой.

(2)  Осенью, *когда  появляются самые разнообразные грибы – **белые, маслята, лисички, опята***, –  начинается настоящая грибная охота.

Это обособление **двумя тире по образцу вставки**. В этом случае **ряд входит в другую обособленную конструкцию.** Похожий вариант есть у Розенталя в теме «Обособленные  приложения»:  *Все мы, воспитатели – **учителя и родители**, –  должны учитывать возрастные особенности в общении с детьми.* В этом случае приложение поясняет другое обособленное приложение.

Еще один известный пример (в учебных текстах вместо первого тире ставят двоеточие).

В Бергене все было по-старому. *Все, что могло приглушить звуки, – **ковры, портьеры и мягкую мебель** – Григ давно убрал из дома.* Остался только старый диван. На нем могло разместиться до десятка гостей, и Григ не решался его выбросить. Друзья говорили, что дом композитора похож на жилище дровосека. Его украшал только рояль (К. Паустовский. Корзина с еловыми шишками).

3. Можно ли в распространенном приложении  **просто добавить тире к запятой** для более удобного прочтения? Я полагаю, что нет. **Интонационное тире** ставится при отсутствии знаков или заменяет другие знаки, но не добавляется к ним. Сочетание «запятая и тире» обозначает или единый знак, или независимую постановку каждого знака по правилам.

Откуда взялось тире в правилах Розенталя и как его можно объяснить  –  вот это непонятно. Мне кажется, что это более **позднее редактирование** – слишком уж свободное и необоснованное обращение с существующими правилами.

Еще раз спасибо за ответ, было очень интересно узнать ваше мнение. Хотя я  не во всем согласилась с вами, но выши рассуждения помогли мне определиться в этой теме.

Answer (score 1):

> Розенталь приводит два предложения, в одном из которых тире
> сохраняется, а в другом – поглощается запятой.
> https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103 п.8
>
> *Наряду с иными стихийными бедствиями, как-то: пожар, град, начисто
> выбивающий хлебные поля, ненастье или, наоборот, великая сушь, — есть
> в деревне ещё одно бедствие* (Сол.)
>
> *Владелец тщательно осведомляется о ценах на разные большие
> произведения, как-то: муку, пеньку, мёд и прочее, но покупает только
> небольшие безделушки* (Г.)
>
> Всё бы хорошо, но как объяснить **разное решение для сходных вариантов?**
> В обоих случаях после однородного ряда стоит запятая.

Запятая стоит в обоих случаях, но в первом предложении она обусловлена **впереди стоящей конструкцией** (закрывает оборот с предложным сочетанием наряду с), а во втором —конструкцией, **стоящей после перечисления**.

Тире же, по мнению Розенталя, должно опускаться только в тех случаях, когда постановка запятой требуется структурой части предложения, **стоящей после перечисления.**

См.:

> Если однородные члены, стоящие после обобщающего слова, не заканчивают
> собой предложения, то перед ними ставится двоеточие, а после них —
> тире...
>
> Постановка перед тире также запятой в качестве дополнительного
> пунктуационного знака связана с условиями контекста, т. е. обусловлена
> каким-либо другим правилом...
>
> **Если постановка запятой требуется структурой последней части предложения, стоящей после перечисления** [выделено мной. — slava1947]
> **то тире опускается и ставится только запятая**...

https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/81920160.html